# Unreal Source Build Hangs in xcode

Tags: xcode, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to build my Unreal Engine project using Unreal source with the generated Xcode workspace. Xcode or xcodebuild however, just hangs soon after the build process starts. I can't find any useful info in the system logs, build logs, or anything as to why this would just hang. It's not taking a long time, my CPU is almost idle.

Has anyone ran into this issue? I'm not getting a response on this topic on Unreals forums in over 2 months.

```
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild build -workspace Multiplayer.xcworkspace -scheme Multiplayer

2020-08-07 17:35:47.120 xcodebuild[49986:170299] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/UnrealEngine-4.25.3-release/Engine/Config/TVOS/TVOSEngine.ini" failed, errno = 2
2020-08-07 17:35:47.311 xcodebuild[49986:170299] +dataWithFirstBytes:1024 ofFile:"/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/UnrealEngine-4.25.3-release/Engine/Plugins/FX/Niagara/Source/Niagara/Private/NiagaraRendererLights" failed, errno = 2
Prepare build
note: Using legacy build system
Build Preparation
Build task concurrency set to 8 via user default IDEBuildOperationMaxNumberOfConcurrentCompileTasks

=== BUILD LEGACY TARGET Multiplayer_Build OF PROJECT Multiplayer WITH CONFIGURATION Development Editor ===

Check dependencies

ExternalBuildToolExecution Multiplayer_Build
    cd /Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/UnrealEngine-4.25.3-release
    export ACTION=
    export ALTERNATE_GROUP=staff
    export ALTERNATE_MODE=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export ALTERNATE_OWNER=byronwright
    export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS=NO
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/AppleInternal/Developer
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR=/AppleInternal
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/AppleInternal/Documentation
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/AppleInternal/Library
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
    export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS=NO
    export ARCHS=x86_64
    export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS="appletvos appletvsimulator iphoneos iphonesimulator macosx watchos watchsimulator"
    export BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=marker
    export BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY=NO
    export BUILD_COMPONENTS="headers build"
    export BUILD_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build
    export BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=NO
    export BUILD_ROOT=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build
    export BUILD_STYLE=
    export BUILD_VARIANTS=normal
    export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Development Editor"
    export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/
    export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH_deep=Contents/
    export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_NAME_deep=MacOS
    export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/MacOS
    export BUNDLE_FORMAT=deep
    export BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/Frameworks
    export BUNDLE_PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/PlugIns
    export BUNDLE_PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/PrivateHeaders
    export BUNDLE_PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH=Contents/Headers
    export CACHE_ROOT=/var/folders/zs/7_1tgdbj5f7_33s1dg3bzng00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/11.5-11E608c/Xcode
    export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD=c++14
    export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE=/Users/byronwright/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
    export CLASS_FILE_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build/JavaClasses"
    export CLONE_HEADERS=NO
    export CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES
    export CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=-
    export CODE_SIGN_INJECT_BASE_ENTITLEMENTS=YES
    export COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS=YES
    export COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=Default
    export CONFIGURATION="Development Editor"
    export CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Development Editor"
    export CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor"
    export COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA=NO
    export COPY_HEADERS_RUN_UNIFDEF=NO
    export COPY_PHASE_STRIP=YES
    export CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY=NO
    export DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING=NO
    export DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES
    export DEFAULT_COMPILER=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export DEFAULT_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
    export DEFAULT_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export DEFINES_MODULE=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION=NO
    export DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=NO
    export DERIVED_FILES_DIR=
    export DERIVED_FILE_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build/DerivedSources"
    export DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build/DerivedSources"
    export DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    export DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
    export DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
    export DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE=English
    export DONT_GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE=NO
    export DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM=NO
    export DSTROOT=/tmp/Multiplayer.dst
    export DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME=.dSYM
    export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT=NO
    export DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Development Editor"
    export EMBEDDED_PROFILE_NAME=embedded.provisionprofile
    export EMBED_ASSET_PACKS_IN_PRODUCT_BUNDLE=NO
    export ENABLE_BITCODE=NO
    export ENABLE_DEFAULT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS=YES
    export ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME=NO
    export ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES=NO
    export ENABLE_TESTABILITY=NO
    export ENABLE_TESTING_SEARCH_PATHS=NO
    export EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS=".DS_Store .svn .git .hg CVS"
    export EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES="*.nib *.lproj *.framework *.gch *.xcode* *.xcassets (*) .DS_Store CVS .svn .git .hg *.pbproj *.pbxproj"
    export FILE_LIST="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build/Objects/LinkFileList"
    export FRAMEWORK_VERSION=A
    export GCC3_VERSION=3.3
    export GCC_ENABLE_CPP_RTTI=NO
    export GCC_VERSION=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
    export GCC_WARN_CHECK_SWITCH_STATEMENTS=NO
    export GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE=NO
    export GENERATE_PKGINFO_FILE=NO
    export GENERATE_PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export GENERATE_TEXT_BASED_STUBS=NO
    export GID=20
    export GROUP=staff
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FLAT_ENTRIES_FOR_TARGET_BEING_BUILT=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_FRAMEWORK_ENTRIES_FOR_ALL_PRODUCT_TYPES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_NONPUBLIC_NONPRIVATE_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_INCLUDES_PROJECT_HEADERS=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_FRAMEWORK_PREFIX_ENTRIES=YES
    export HEADERMAP_USES_VFS=NO
    export HIDE_BITCODE_SYMBOLS=YES
    export HOME=/Users/byronwright
    export INFOPLIST_EXPAND_BUILD_SETTINGS=YES
    export INFOPLIST_OUTPUT_FORMAT=same-as-input
    export INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS=NO
    export INLINE_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS=NO
    export INSTALLHDRS_COPY_PHASE=NO
    export INSTALLHDRS_SCRIPT_PHASE=NO
    export INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/Multiplayer.dst
    export INSTALL_GROUP=staff
    export INSTALL_MODE_FLAG=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export INSTALL_OWNER=byronwright
    export INSTALL_ROOT=/tmp/Multiplayer.dst
    export JAVA_APP_STUB=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES=YES
    export JAVA_ARCHIVE_TYPE=JAR
    export JAVA_COMPILER=/usr/bin/javac
    export JAVA_FRAMEWORK_RESOURCES_DIRS=Resources
    export JAVA_JAR_FLAGS=cv
    export JAVA_SOURCE_SUBDIR=.
    export JAVA_USE_DEPENDENCIES=YES
    export JAVA_ZIP_FLAGS=-urg
    export KEEP_PRIVATE_EXTERNS=NO
    export LD_DEPENDENCY_INFO_FILE=//_dependency_info.dat
    export LD_GENERATE_MAP_FILE=NO
    export LD_MAP_FILE_PATH="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build/-LinkMap--.txt"
    export LD_NO_PIE=NO
    export LD_QUOTE_LINKER_ARGUMENTS_FOR_COMPILER_DRIVER=YES
    export LEGACY_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer
    export LIBRARY_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/Library/DriverExtensions
    export LIBRARY_FLAG_NOSPACE=YES
    export LIBRARY_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/Library/Extensions
    export LINKER_DISPLAYS_MANGLED_NAMES=NO
    export LINK_WITH_STANDARD_LIBRARIES=YES
    export LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_OS_VERSION=macos10.15
    export LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLE_VENDOR=apple
    export LOCALIZED_STRING_MACRO_NAMES="NSLocalizedString CFCopyLocalizedString"
    export LOCALIZED_STRING_SWIFTUI_SUPPORT=YES
    export LOCAL_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export LOCAL_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export LOCAL_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Library/Developer
    export LOCAL_LIBRARY_DIR=/Library
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.15
    export MAC_OS_X_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=19F101
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_ACTUAL=101505
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAJOR=101500
    export MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MINOR=1505
    export METAL_LIBRARY_FILE_BASE=default
    export METAL_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Development Editor/"
    export MODULE_CACHE_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex
    export OBJECT_FILE_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build/Objects"
    export OBJROOT=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build
    export ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO
    export OS=MACOS
    export PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES="/usr/include /usr/local/include /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Headers /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms"
    export PLATFORM_NAME=macosx
    export PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT=same-as-input
    export PRECOMPS_INCLUDE_HEADERS_FROM_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR=YES
    export PRECOMP_DESTINATION_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build/PrefixHeaders"
    export PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS=NO
    export PRODUCT_NAME=
    export PROFILING_CODE=NO
    export PROJECT=Multiplayer
    export PROJECT_DERIVED_FILE_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/DerivedSources
    export PROJECT_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles
    export PROJECT_FILE_PATH=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/Multiplayer.xcodeproj
    export PROJECT_NAME=Multiplayer
    export PROJECT_TEMP_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build
    export PROJECT_TEMP_ROOT=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build
    export REMOVE_CVS_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_GIT_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES=YES
    export REMOVE_HG_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export REMOVE_SVN_FROM_RESOURCES=YES
    export SCAN_ALL_SOURCE_FILES_FOR_INCLUDES=NO
    export SDKROOT=
    export SEPARATE_STRIP=NO
    export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT=NO
    export SHARED_DERIVED_FILE_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Development Editor/DerivedSources"
    export SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/SharedPrecompiledHeaders
    export SKIP_INSTALL=YES
    export SOURCE_ROOT=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles
    export SRCROOT=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles
    export STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING=UTF-16
    export STRIP_BITCODE_FROM_COPIED_FILES=NO
    export STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES
    export STRIP_STYLE=all
    export STRIP_SWIFT_SYMBOLS=YES
    export SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS=macosx
    export SUPPORTS_TEXT_BASED_API=NO
    export SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX=macos
    export SYMROOT=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build
    export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR=/Applications
    export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR=/System/Library/CoreServices
    export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR=/Applications/Extras
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_APPS_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DEMOS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Built Examples"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_GRAPHICS_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_JAVA_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Java Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_PERFORMANCE_TOOLS_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Performance Tools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DOC_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/documentation/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_TOOLS_RELEASENOTES_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/ADC Reference Library/releasenotes/DeveloperTools"
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_USR_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
    export SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_UTILITIES_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Utilities
    export SYSTEM_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
    export SYSTEM_DOCUMENTATION_DIR=/Library/Documentation
    export SYSTEM_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH=/System/Library/Extensions
    export SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR=/System/Library
    export TAPI_VERIFY_MODE=ErrorsOnly
    export TARGETNAME=Multiplayer_Build
    export TARGET_BUILD_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Development Editor"
    export TARGET_NAME=Multiplayer_Build
    export TARGET_TEMP_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build"
    export TEMP_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build"
    export TEMP_FILES_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build"
    export TEMP_FILE_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Multiplayer.build/Development Editor/Multiplayer_Build.build"
    export TEMP_ROOT=/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build
    export TOOLCHAIN_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export TREAT_MISSING_BASELINES_AS_TEST_FAILURES=NO
    export UE_BUILD_TARGET_CONFIG=Development
    export UE_BUILD_TARGET_NAME=MultiplayerEditor
    export UID=501
    export UIKITFORMAC_SWIFT_TOOLCHAIN_LIBRARY_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/maccatalyst
    export USER=byronwright
    export USER_APPS_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Applications
    export USER_LIBRARY_DIR=/Users/byronwright/Library
    export USE_HEADERMAP=NO
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES=YES
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_CLANG=YES
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_LD=YES
    export USE_LLVM_TARGET_TRIPLES_FOR_TAPI=YES
    export VALIDATE_WORKSPACE=NO
    export VALID_ARCHS=x86_64
    export WATCH_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="/Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Intermediate/ProjectFiles/build/Development Editor-watchos"
    export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES=NO
    export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
    export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION=11E608c
    export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL=1150
    export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR=1100
    export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR=1150
    export arch=x86_64
    export diagnostic_message_length=254
    export variant=normal
    /Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/UnrealEngine-4.25.3-release/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac/XcodeBuild.sh MultiplayerEditor macosx Development /Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Multiplayer.uproject -buildscw
Running system mono/msbuild, version: Mono JIT compiler version 6.8.0.105 (2019-10/82fffe07497 Tue Feb  4 10:09:51 EST 2020)
Building MultiplayerEditor...
Building ShaderCompileWorker...
Target is up to date
Deploying ShaderCompileWorker Mac Development...
Deploying now!
Total execution time: 0.92 seconds
Running command : Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe MultiplayerEditor Mac Development /Users/byronwright/Projects/Unreal/Multiplayer_4.25/Multiplayer.uproject -buildscw
```

Comment: Same issue here, 2014 macbook pro. Doing a git clean -fdx then a build will work after a few hours. But attempting a second build causes it to hang. I also can't build a new project, it just hangs.

Comment: @joshmmo yeah clean build fixes it. Unfortunately, after clean build, the issue comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue, can't say for sure you're having the same. But the problem is that `/bin/ps -eaw -o pid,comm` may produce over 64K of output data. Run `/bin/ps -eaw -o pid,comm | wc` to see if that's the case.

This may sound quite far-fetched, but inside `BuildHostPlatorm.cs` in the class `MacBuildHostPlatform` and method `GetProcesses()` a process call is made with that command:

```
    Proc.Start();
    Proc.WaitForExit();
    // ... then output is read
```

So if the output is larger than the pipe buffer the command gets stuck. This has been solved in 4.27 by moving the `Proc.WaitForExit()` until after reading output from the process. If you're on earlier versions, just move the `WaitForExit();` to right after the reading loop.

It's on lines 283-... in the file `Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/System/BuildHostPlatform.cs`

/ Patric